# Combining 4 columns in mysql

Tags: mysql

Good day, I have a question. I have a query here that will combine 4 columns. I read it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp).

here's my query

> SELECT CustomerSelection, LastName+', '+FirstName+', '+StationNo FROM
>   `sampledb`.`sampletable`;

But it doesn't work. Why? I know that using CONCAT will solve it. But I want to try another way. Thanks

Comment: `concat` is the function to solve this issue where `+` an add operator which is for adding values not concat.

Comment: use this link http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_alias_column2&ss=-1

Comment: Didn't you read the NOTE below the example on the site you mention? "Note: To get the SQL statement above to work in MySQL use the following:"

Comment: @TZHX. only the stationno shown but lastname and firstname are not.

Comment: @Ctx. So this is for MSSql only?

Comment: I honestly do not know, which database accepts this syntax. Maybe mssql. Postgresql for example would use || for string concatenation

Comment: thank you guys for helping me

Comment: @jLaw:- Just FYI, some people do not recommend to use w3schools.com .

Comment: @RahulTripathi. And why is that? thank you for the info

Comment: @jLaw:- Please do mind that I said, some people. Also here is a related discussion: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120621/w3fools-alternatives

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function in Mysql(*and why to avoid it?*). Try this:

```
SELECT CustomerSelection, CONCAT(LastName,', ',FirstName,', ',StationNo) 
FROM sampledb.sampletable;
```

or you can use

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(',', LastName, FirstName, StationNo)
FROM sampledb.sampletable;
```

Answer (score 1):

Strangely the link you gave has the answer to your question as well

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Only **CONCAT()** function can combine columns.

```
SELECT CONCAT(CustomerSelection, LastName, FirstName, StationNo) FROM sampledb.sampletable;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using '+' you can use ||.

SELECT CustomerSelection||LastName||FirstName||StationNo FROM sampledb.sampletable;

Comment: If you want comma in between the results of different columns then use below query.

SELECT CustomerSelection,  LastName || ', ' || FirstName || ', ' || StationNo FROM sampledb.sampletable;

Answer (score 0):

If you want comma in between the results of different columns then use below query.

SELECT CustomerSelection, LastName || ', ' || FirstName || ', ' || StationNo FROM sampledb.sampletable;